# unable to send messages From SendPort to ReceivePort in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

I'm trying to send a message via the IsolateNameServer in flutter.

However, I am unable to receive messages. I've tried checking if the receiver port is listening by calling `port.listen()` twice, and it says that it is already listening.

Where am I going wrong? [ I am closely following [this documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager#-example-tab-) ]

Here is my main.dart, based on the above doc:

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
const String isolateName = 'isolate';

main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
    port.sendPort,
    isolateName,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            accentColor: Colors.pink,
            floatingActionButtonTheme:
                FloatingActionButtonThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.pink)),
        home: AlarmManagerExample());
  }
}

class AlarmManagerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AlarmManagerExampleState createState() => _AlarmManagerExampleState();
}

class _AlarmManagerExampleState extends State<AlarmManagerExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
    port.listen((_) async => await workForMe());
  }

  workForMe() async {
    print("Secondary Function Triggered!");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(const Duration(seconds: 5),
                Random().nextInt(pow(2, 21)), callback);
          },
          child: Text(
            "Alarm Manager",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static SendPort uiSendPort;

  static callback() {
    print("Callbacks Triggered!");

    // This will be null if we're running in the background.
    uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    uiSendPort?.send(null);
  }
}
```

The output I am getting is :

```
Callbacks Triggered!
```

However, the expected output is:

```
Callbacks Triggered!
Secondary Function Triggered!
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that error is caused because the workForMe() function isn't static. Moreover, I don't know if callBacks support Future or async.

With that said, try this, as there is no need to make it async.

```
 static void workForMe() {
   print("Secondary Function Triggered!");
 }
```